# Comparison of list to list of lists and return the other element from the list of list

Tags: python, list, tuples

I have a list - answers:

```
[0,1]
```

and another list of list - questions:

```
[[0,ABC], [1,DEF], [3,XYZ]]
```

How can I compare the 2 and return

```
 ABC, DEF
```

based on the comparison of all elements in answers to first elements in the list of list?

Comment: It's not clear whether the order of the output is important, and if so is it defined by the order of the answers or of the questions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) and keep the second items in `questions`
 if the first item is contained in `answers` :

```
answers = set([0,1])
[i[1] for i in questions if i[0] in answers]
# ['ABC', 'DEF']
```

---

*Note:* Using a set instead of a list helps drop the complexity from `O(N*M)` to `O(N)` as suggested by @RafaelC, with `N` being the length of questions and `M` length of answers

Comment: Might want to change `answers` to be a `set`. Complexity goes from `O(N*M)` to `O(N)` where `N` is loength of questions and `M` is length of answers

Answer (score 1):

Since you mentioned `pandas`

```
pd.DataFrame([[0,'ABC'], [1,'DEF'], [3,'XYZ']]).loc[lambda x : x[0].isin([0,1])][1].tolist()
Out[494]: ['ABC', 'DEF']
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
[i[1] for i in lst2 if i[0] in lst1]
```

Though I don't understand what this has anything to do with pandas though.